# Why my array's last index returns false when it was supposed to return true? JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm doing a university assignment where i must write an algorithm to check if a number is prime or not. To accomplish that i've written a method that creates an array with all prime numbers till the given number, aftwards i'm trying to check if the last index of the array == true, cause it happens, then that number is prime, if not, then it's not. For example:

number = 6, it will create an array with:
2, 3 and 5 having true values, while the rest of the do not, so array[6] should be false. The problem is, the index n is always getting the false value, when apparently it shouldn't. Here's the code:

```
    public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        boolean primes[] = new boolean[n + 1];
        
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            primes[i] = true;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (primes[i] == true) {
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(primes[i]);
                for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {
                    primes[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // idk why but it doesnt work as expected?
        if (primes[n] == true) {
            System.out.println(n);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(n);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

if i do isPrime(7) i get the following result:

*2
true
3
true
5
true
7
true
7
false
*

I've tried to change the index but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {` sets first value to false, it should be `for (int j = i+i; j <= n; j += i) {`

Comment: Off-topic / style: You don't have to compare `boolean` variables to Boolean constants (i.e., `true` , `false`). If `foo` is a boolean variable, `if (foo == true)` is equivlent to `if (foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your error:

You don't know how to debug. It's a skill; a thing you learn.

Debugging is quite simple. In basis, you simply walk through the code and think about what it should be doing. Then you run it and check what it actually does. Line by line. Every time there is a difference between what the code actually does, and what you thought it would do - you found 1 bug. There might be a few; fix it, and restart the process until the application responds exactly as you planned it to at all points.

A debugger is a nice tool for this, but, if that sounds too daunting to learn right now (know that you'll never amount to more than a bad junior programmer if you don't know how to use one, so, one day you'll have to bite into it) - you can just use a load of `System.out.println` statements.

WHen you do that, you'll find that in fact **every** number is false. You print 'too early' to see that right now - add more prints and you'll see that.

When you specifically investigate your loop that 'marks off' multiples of primes, you'll find that you're marking off the number itself. In other words, when 'sweeping out' for, say, 3, you are supposed to mark off 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, and so on as not prime. You *also* mark 3 off as not prime - you end up with every number marked off as not prime.

This is the line: `for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {  primes[j] = false; }`

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code in the nested for loops, try the below code **remember: these loop's continuation conditions and loop increments based on mathematical theories about prime numbers, so it's a bit confusing.**

```
public class GetPrimes {
        public static void printPrimesUntil(int n)
        {
    
            boolean prime[] = new boolean[n + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                prime[i] = true;
     
            for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
                
                if (prime[p] == true) {
                    
                    for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                        prime[i] = false;
                }
            }
     
            // Print all prime numbers, do whatever u want with prime array
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                if (prime[i] == true)
                    System.out.print(i + " ,");
            }
        }
      
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int N = 20;
            System.out.println("All the Prime numbers until " + N + " are :");
            printPrimesUntil(N);
        }
    }
```

or you can implement it dependent on the theory of (**prime number is dividable only on itself and 1**), think it's easy.